# Eclipse kepler > aptana plugin > css editor

Tags: css, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, formatting, aptana3

I have recently instaled eclipse kepler and aptana plugin for as editors.
My problem is when I want to format code on *css files because nothing happens. If someone encountered this problem and have a solution for that pls share.
Or if someone has a better ideea for a new plugin editor for css and html/js to work in eclipse kepler I will be grateful.
Ty.

Comment: When you right-click on the CSS file, does the Open With menu list more than one CSS Editor?  If so, have you tried both?

Comment: I have installed juno version of eclipse, kepler version is too buggy.